# NoSuchMethodException with javax.servlet.http.Cookie using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I am currently calling `javax.servlet.http.Cookie` and receiving the `NoSuchMethodException` while running a program in Eclipse. The `javax.servlet-api-4.0.0.x.jar` is in the build path.
Here is the code that I am running currently:

```
method = cms.getClass().getMethod(field, javax.servlet.http.Cookie.class);
```

I have also tried:

```
method = cms.getClass().getMethod(field, Cookie.class);
```

There is also an import for `import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;`. The object `cms` is a `Class` for connecting to a SQL server and `field` is a `String` containing the name of a method to be called.

Comment: What are the type of `cms` and the value of `field`?

Comment: `cms` is a `Class` I wrote for contacting a SQL server and `field` is a `String` containing the method to be called.

Comment: suppose this project is maven project it would be helpful if you could share the `pom.xml`. Think there is a dependency issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use `getDeclaredMethod(field, Cookie.class)`.

`getMethod(...)` only returns *public* members.

Comment: That was the problem! Thank you for the help!

Comment: I've made that mistake a few times myself ;)